# KOMA-Script adds extra space when switching to certain font sizes

Tags: koma-script, fontsize

The KOMA-Script key `fontsize` can be used to switch the font size mid-document (as well as at the start of the document). However, it adds spurious spaces when switching to `10pt`, `11pt` or `12pt`, as can be seen in the MWE below. This seems to only happen for those sizes.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\def\fontsizetest#1{%
  \noindent\makebox[2em][r]{#1}:
  {X\KOMAoptions{fontsize=#1}X}\par
}

\begin{document}

\fontsizetest{9pt}
\fontsizetest{9.5pt}
\fontsizetest{10pt}
\fontsizetest{10.5pt}
\fontsizetest{11pt}
\fontsizetest{11.5pt}
\fontsizetest{12pt}
\fontsizetest{12.5pt}
\fontsizetest{13pt}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: It will be some missing `%` in the class but do you ever really want to change the document layout mid-paragraph? spaces are harmless in vertical mode

Comment: there is probably a spurious space somewhere. KOMA has a bug tracker, report it (but imho this options shouldn't be used in the middle of a document).

Comment: If you just want to change the fontsize, don't use this, use the standard latex `\fontsize` command

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But `\fontsize` doesn't set up `\large` and friends, does it? KOMA-Script changes all of those, as well as setting up dimensions like `\abovedisplayskip`.

Comment: I agree that the font size should not usually be changed mid-document, but I believe there are reasonable exceptions. The KOMA-Script documentation itself mentions wanting to typeset an appendix in a slightly smaller font size. In my case, I am typesetting a poster with a large font size and want to include some `tikzpictures` that I need to scale up (using `adjustbox`; there is no good way to scale all the relevant dimensions using Ti*k*Z itself), so I need to reset the font size to a small value for the `tikzpictures`.

Comment: I guess an alternative would be to typeset the whole poster small and then scale up the entire document, but switching now is more work than just changing the font size for the `tikzpictures`.

Comment: exactly, why would you want to reset lengths such as `\abovedisplayskip` _mid-paragraph_ ?

Comment: if it doesn't need to be mid-pargraph put `\par` in front so the changes happen in vmode and spaces are ignored

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Fair point. However, in my case I want to do `\AddToHook{env/tikzpicture/begin}{\KOMAoptions{fontsize=11pt}}` and then `\begin{adjustbox}{scale=3}\begin{tikzpicture}\node{test};\end{tikzpicture}\end{adjustbox}`. I can't ensure that the `tikzpicture` will be in vertical mode. In the particular case of being inside `adjustbox`, it is not.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a "known" size then a pre-made size-file is loaded and the log says

```
Class scrartcl Info: File `scrsize12pt.clo' used to setup font sizes on input l
ine 18.
```

Looking at  `scrsize12pt.clo` you see things like

```
\def\small{%
  \@setfontsize\small\@xipt{13.6}%
  \abovedisplayskip 11\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
  \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
  \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
    \topsep 9\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus5\p@
    \parsep 4.5\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@
    \itemsep \parsep}%
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
```

Where the newline after `}` makes a space token if used in horizontal mode.

It is rare to change document layout mid-document, and almost never a requirement to change *mid-paragraph* so newlines after definitions haven't been guarded by `%` here.

Comment: as a workaround, if switching to `vmode` is not an option, follow by enough `\unskip\unskip...`